# Is there any chance to make keyboard to shows over tab icons

Tags: android, android-widget, android-windowmanager

I have tabs at the bottom on my activity. Problem is that I have TextViews on activity and when I want to write text, keyboard shows but keyboard lift up bottom tab icons and make partly invisible TextView. Is there any chance to make keyboard to shows over tab icons ( not to lift up bottom tab icons) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to look around the [`android:windowSoftInputMode`](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/04/updating-applications-for-on-screen.html) which has attributes `adjustResize` and `adjustPan`.

From the link I guess adding `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|adjustPan"` in the Manifest file should do the trick for you.

Answer (score 1):

Try playing around with the softInputMode values of your activity in the manifest, and see what works for your situation.

```
android:windowSoftInputMode
```